# Why does the version shown in the GeneratedCodeAttribute not match the version of the tool generating the web service reference code?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, soap, asmx

We've inherited a legacy application that uses SOAP web services. I'm currently upgrading the .net framework version to 4.8.

When you add a web reference visual studio generates a Reference.cs file. The `GeneratedCodeAttribute` in the current Reference.cs looks like this: `[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Web.Services", "4.6.1055.0")]`

After upgrading it looks like this: `[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Web.Services", "4.8.4084.0")]`

I've been on a bit of a mental journey because I thought the original 4.6.1055.0 was because the project was targeting .net framework 4.6 -- turns out that is not the case.

I created a test project in .net framework 4.5.1 and added a web reference; it displayed as such: `[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Web.Services", "4.8.4084.0")]`

I am now somewhat confident that version number comes from the version of .net framework that visual studio is using.[image]

Also, in the comments of Reference.cs is the version of Microsoft.VSDesigner, which is 4.0.30319.42000.

The version of System.Web.Services that my project is using is 4.5.1 and the version of Microsoft.VSDesigner is 4.0.30319.42000. I would assume to either see `[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Web.Services", "4.5.1")]` or `[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VSDesigner", "4.0.30319.42000")]`

So, my question is: **Why does the GeneratedCodeAttribute specify that the tool that generated the `SoapHttpClientProtocol` is version 4.8 and not 4.5.1?**

If you could describe the call stack that leads to this code generation, that would be a bonus.

Comment: Have similar problem, I want to change the version manually in the file, but I can't even find the full version number for 4.6.2

Comment: @mybirthname What file is it? Is it Reference.cs?